# iframe :Failed to launch <link> because the scheme does not have a registered handler

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, iframe

Estou codando um projeto em html e linkei um google form ao botão de vagas, mais quando clico para abrir o `form` em um dispositivo `Android` ele não abre, procurei na internet o erro mas não aparece nenhuma solução em JS. Segue foto do erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Erro

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Situação do site após o click

erro:

> Failed to launch
> 'intent://forms.gle/APWr5k57KL5ipnH56#Intent;package=com.google.android.gms;action=com.google.firebase.dynamiclinks.VIEW_DYNAMIC_LINK;scheme=https;S.browser_fallback_url=https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSe0PP_iqXIVohaGxyQ8McbnxjJEHcYrev2BrGVMeeknSTyGRQ/viewform%3Fusp%3Dsend_form;end;'
> because the scheme does not have a registered handler.

Comment: Coloque no link o atributo `crossorigin="anonymous"` as vezes ajuda. Mas achei estranho, pq começa com `intent://` ?

Comment: Relacionada: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64797802/what-is-this-scheme-dont-have-a-registered-handler-error

Answer (score 0):

O URL que você está usando está correto. MAS se você estiver tentando isso no simulador, não funcionará e mostrará exatamente o erro. O esquema de URL do aplicativo da App Store ou PlayStore funciona apenas em um dispositivo, nesse caso não está redirecionando pra uma das lojas mas mesmo assim pode ser isso.